# Error while using JsonLoader from elephant-bird-pig

Tags: java, json, apache-pig

I'm trying to use JSonLoader form elephant-bird-pig package.
My script is simple:

```
register elephant-bird-pig-4.5.jar
register elephant-bird-hadoop-compat-4.5.jar

A = load '1_record_2.json' USING com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader('-nestedLoad');

DUMP A
```

And I get an error:

```
2014-09-30 16:15:32,439 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
2014-09-30 16:15:32,447 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.ScriptState - Pig features used in the script: UNKNOWN
2014-09-30 16:15:32,448 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.LogicalPlanOptimizer - {RULES_ENABLED=[AddForEach, ColumnMapKeyPrune, GroupByConstParallelSetter, LimitOptimizer, LoadTypeCastInserter, MergeFilter, MergeForEach, NewPartitionFilterOptimizer, PartitionFilterOptimizer, PushDownForEachFlatten, PushUpFilter, SplitFilter, StreamTypeCastInserter], RULES_DISABLED=[FilterLogicExpressionSimplifier]}
2014-09-30 16:15:32,449 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MRCompiler - File concatenation threshold: 100 optimistic? false
2014-09-30 16:15:32,450 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer - MR plan size before optimization: 1
2014-09-30 16:15:32,450 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer - MR plan size after optimization: 1
2014-09-30 16:15:32,464 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy - Connecting to ResourceManager at hadoop1/10.242.8.131:8050
2014-09-30 16:15:32,466 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.ScriptState - Pig script settings are added to the job
2014-09-30 16:15:32,466 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - mapred.job.reduce.markreset.buffer.percent is not set, set to default 0.3
2014-09-30 16:15:32,467 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. com/twitter/elephantbird/util/HadoopCompat
Details at logfile: pig_1412081068149.log
```

I don't know what is missing. Can you please suggest something?

File pig_1412081068149.log contains:

```
Pig Stack Trace
---------------
ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. com/twitter/elephantbird/util/HadoopCompat

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/twitter/elephantbird/util/HadoopCompat
    at com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.LzoBaseLoadFunc.setLocation(LzoBaseLoadFunc.java:93)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler.getJob(JobControlCompiler.java:477)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler.compile(JobControlCompiler.java:298)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher.launchPig(MapReduceLauncher.java:191)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.launchPlan(PigServer.java:1324)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeCompiledLogicalPlan(PigServer.java:1309)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.storeEx(PigServer.java:980)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.store(PigServer.java:944)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.openIterator(PigServer.java:857)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processDump(GruntParser.java:774) etc...
```

What class is missing (`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`) ? What libraries should I add more?

Thanks
pawel

Comment: NoClassDefFoundError usually means that you have incompatible JAR files.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked if registered libraries exist and classes are inside the libraries.
Everythig looked fine, but I was still getting this error.
So I left pig shell, and opened it once again - the same script works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You missed two important jars to register. 
register elephant-bird-core-4.5.jar
register json-simple-1.1.1.jar

Add these two to your pig script and everything should work fine.